# why og:image is different from what is showed in a FB shared post

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am learning open graph, I don't understand why for this [website](http://linjer.co), the image in the shared post is different from the image in the meta og tag. Screenshots are as follows:

**This is the og:image tag**

[image]

**Its image is**

[image]

**However, if I just post the link (linjer.co) onto my timeline, the image shown is like this:**

What is wrong?
[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Flinjer.co%2F

Answer (score 0):

You should check your new image ratio to have a nice display on Facebook. see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

cheers